# Converting dot in comma in Visual C#

Tags: c#, math, visual-studio-2013, calculator

I've met a problem during programming a calculator in Visual C#. I want to make an automatic conversion when I write in Textbox, during execution, "." (dot) in "," (comma). These conversion code I wrote doesn't work properly:

```
string s = textBox1.Text;
       int nr = s.Length;
       char[] a = s.ToCharArray();

        for (int i=1; i<=nr; i++)
        {
            if (a[i] == '.')
                a[i] = ',';
        }
```

What should be corrected here? Thanks in advance.

P.S. I'm sorry if this kind of thread already exists here, I couldn't find something like that.

Comment: `string s = textBox1.Text.Replace(".", ",");`

Comment: Or you can add at the end of your code: `s = new string(a);`

Comment: Do you have any specific reason for not opting `String.Replace`?

Comment: And your for shoud be `for (int i=0; i<nr; i++)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
tbTest.KeyUp += ((o, e) =>
            {
                switch (e.Key)
                {
                    case Key.OemPeriod:
                        #if DEBUG
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Period pressed");
                        #endif
                        var tb = (TextBox)o;
                        tb.Text = tb.Text.Replace(".", ","); //Replace period with comma
                        tb.Select(tb.Text.Length, 0);
                        break;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void TextBox1_KeyPress(System.Object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == '.') {
            e.KeyChar = ',';
        }
    }
```